# Infinite loop "saving document" with libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

A docx document in Libreoffice at one point got into an infinite loop where the status line flashed "saving document". I was not able to interrupt it. I managed to close the window and save to ODT, but certain objects was lost in that file format, - apparently.

I am wondering what made Libreoffice get into this infinite loop and whether there are any tricks to make it stop and save the document?

Besides "saving document", I see a popup window with "Error saving the document : General Error. General input/output error."

Update:

with `$ journalctl --since="- 4 hours"`, I find the only libreoffice match to be:

```
Jul 08 23:03:38 <server> dbus-daemon[870]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.10713' (uid=1000 pid=415 comm="/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin <document>" label="unconfined")
```

Comment: What can you tell us about the place you were trying to save the file? Mount status, directory ownership/permission, your `UID:GID`? The results of `journal --since="- 10 minutes"` shortly after the failure? Workaround: Save the documen in some other directory.

Comment: @waltinator, I think you mean `journalctl --since ...`.

Comment: I have put up a line from journalctl. However, I was/is under impression that it was an application error, - not a system error. There is no problem with saving in the directory.

Comment: I suspect the specific Word document you were working with contains features that LibreOffice is unable to handle. Consider filing a bug report with the LibreOffice developers. They will need a copy of a document that causes the same problems.

Comment: I ran into the same issue on windows so that looks like libreoffice bug. And right now trying to figure out how I can avoid losing the whole document

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: hit Ctrl-S a few times. After 3 or 4 tries, usually one of them will register, and the autosave loop will then stop. Unless you're likely to need something in your undo history, I would then close LibreOffice and reopen it, in case any of its internal state is in a mess.

This is, sadly, a known bug in LibreOffice, and remarkably it's been around for at least 6 years without getting fixed. I just had this happen to me, and realising I could stop it with Ctrl-S I thought I should put that information online somewhere, hence this somewhat late reply.

LibreOffice is very useful software, but has a lot of bugs. Regardless of ideological positions on free vs proprietary software, I still use MS Office XP often, and I can say unreservedly it never crashes on me, loses my work or behaves in unexpected ways. I've not used later versions of Office much because I hate the new design, but if you have access to Office 2000/2002/2003/XP you can install the compatibility pack that makes it natively support docx, xlsx etc.

I use mine in a WinXP virtual machine that's not connected to a network, and it complements the Linux host very well. It's also **way** faster, and hundreds of megabytes lighter on memory, for what it's worth. (You can run these versions under Wine also, but some versions are easier to install than others. I believe 2003 installs without trouble if you consider going that route, although I'd consult the Wine software status database first.)

I mention the use of MS Office partly because I've found a lot of people assume a VM and Office will together consume a lot of RAM, and are surprised to learn that memory usage is actually less than using a native application. For me, LibreOffice wins when I want to quickly export something as a PDF, and is easier to print from than a non-networked VM.

Comment: issue is still present lol